# Does it make sense to reuse Runnables in a thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, threadpool, runnable

I'm implementing a thread pool for processing a high volume market data feed and have a question about the strategy of reusing my worker instances that implement runnable which are submitted to the thread pool for execution. In my case I only have one type of worker that takes a String and parses it to create a Quote object which is then set on the correct Security. Given the amount of data coming off the feed it is possible to have upwards of 1,000 quotes to process per second and I see two ways to create the workers that get submitted to the thread pool.

First option is simply creating a new instance of a Worker every time a line is retrieved from the underlying socket and then adding it to the thread pool which will eventually be garbage collected after its run method executed. But then this got me thinking about performance, does it really make sense to instantiate 1,0000 new instances of the Worker class every second. In the same spirit as a thread pool do people know if it is a common pattern to have a runnable pool or queue as well so I can recycle my workers to avoid object creation and garbage collection. The way I see this being implemented is before returning in the run() method the Worker adds itself back to a queue of available workers which is then drawn from when processing new feed lines instead of creating new instances of Worker.

From a performance perspective, do I gain anything by going with the second approach or does the first make more sense? Has anyone implemented this type of pattern before?

Thanks - Duncan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a library I wrote called Java Chronicle for this.  It is designed to persist and queue one million quotes per second without producing any significant garbage.

I have a demo [here](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Chronicle/tree/master/chronicle-demo) where it sends quote like objects with nano second timing information at a rate of one million messages per second and it can send tens of millions in a JVM with a 32 MB heap without triggering even a minor collection. The round trip latency is less than 0.6 micro-seconds 90% of the time on my ultra book. ;)

> from a performance perspective, do I gain anything by going with the second approach or does the first make more sense?

I strongly recommend not filling your CPU caches with garbage.  In fact I avoid any constructs which create any significant garbage.  You can build a system which creates less than one object per event *end to end*.  I have a Eden size which is larger than the amount of garbage I produce in a day so no GCs minor or full to worry about.

> Has anyone implemented this type of pattern before?

I wrote a profitable low latency trading system in Java five years ago. At the time it was fast enough at 60 micro-seconds tick to trade in Java, but you can do better than that these days.

If you want low latency market data processing system, this is the way I do it.  You might find this presentation I gave at JavaOne interesting as well.

http://www.slideshare.net/PeterLawrey/writing-and-testing-high-frequency-trading-engines-in-java

---

EDIT I have added this [parsing example](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/tree/master/lang/src/test/java/net/openhft/lang/io/examples/ParserExampleMain.java)

```
ByteBuffer wrap = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
ByteBufferBytes bufferBytes = new ByteBufferBytes(wrap);
byte[] bytes = "BAC,12.32,12.54,12.56,232443".getBytes();

int runs = 10000000;
long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
    bufferBytes.reset();
    // read the next message.
    bufferBytes.write(bytes);
    bufferBytes.position(0);
    // decode message
    String word = bufferBytes.parseUTF(StopCharTesters.COMMA_STOP);
    double low = bufferBytes.parseDouble();
    double curr = bufferBytes.parseDouble();
    double high = bufferBytes.parseDouble();
    long sequence = bufferBytes.parseLong();
    if (i == 0) {
        assertEquals("BAC", word);
        assertEquals(12.32, low, 0.0);
        assertEquals(12.54, curr, 0.0);
        assertEquals(12.56, high, 0.0);
        assertEquals(232443, sequence);
    }
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.println("Average time was " + time / runs + " nano-seconds");
```

when set with -verbose:gc -Xmx32m it prints

```
Average time was 226 nano-seconds
```

Note: there are no GCes triggered.

Comment: What do you think is the best way to parse a string like "BAC,12.32,12.54,12.56,232443" etc. into a Quote object. I'm doing that thousands of times a second and right now I'm doing string[].split[,] and then casting each value to its type.

Comment: Chronicle is based on Java-Lang. It can parse the whole original bytes from wherever they came from without creating garbage.  If you want the plain JDK you can use Scanner and at least the primitives can be read without garbage.

Comment: @DuncanKrebs I have added an example of how I would do it.  I would avoid using a heap buffer at all, reading into direct memory, but I don't know your restrictions.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I'm taking a look at this now going to to implement in my Runnable and see how it performs!

Comment: Great Code!!! + I learned some new things about Java. I do have a question, is to not have to sequentially parse the comma separated values if I'm only interested in say 10 of the 50 values or do I have to parse each one?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the `Executor` from the concurrency package.  I believe it handles all this for you.

Comment: Was it a good question? if so up vote it! I'm going to look at the Executor and accept answer if I see the solution or post a question so I can accept your answer.

Comment: If you want low latency, don't use the ExecutorServices.  For anything else you should consider it first.

Comment: I don't understand this answer -- or why it was accepted.  How does using the `Executor` interface help with the problem of creating too many `Worker` instances?  Can you flesh it out @duffymo?  Thanks.

Comment: I think BlockingDequeue w/ Executor consumers might work, but after reading Peter Lawrey's answer below I'd give serious thought to accepting that instead.  I can't speak to what others did, but I thought it better to use what's available than to implement Runnables in a custom pool.

Answer (score 1):

> does it really make sense to instantiate 1,0000 new instances of the Worker class every second.

Not necessarily however you are going to have to be putting the `Runnable`s into some sort of `BlockingQueue` to be able to be reused and the cost of the queue concurrency may outweigh the GC overhead.  Using a profiler or watching the GC numbers via Jconsole will tell you if it is spending a lot of time in GC and this needs to be addressed.

If this does turn out to be a problem, a different approach would be to just put your `String` into your own `BlockingQueue` and submit the `Worker` objects to the thread-pool only once.  Each of the `Worker` instances would dequeue from the queue of `String`s and would never quit. Something like:

```
public void run() {
    while (!shutdown) {
        String value = myQueue.take();
        ...
    }
}
```

So you would not need to create your 1000s of `Worker`s per second.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, something like [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trpool), because OS and JVM don't care about what is going on a thread, so generally this is a good practice to reuse a recyclable object.

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions in your problem. One is about thread pooling, and another is about object pooling. For your thread pooling issue, Java has provided an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) . Below is an example of using an ExecutorService.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Do some work
    }
};

// Thread pool of size 2
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
// Add the runnables to the executor service
executor.execute(r);
```

The ExecutorService provides many different types of thread pools with different behaviors.

As far as object pooling is concerned, (Does it make sense to create 1000 of your objects per second, then leave them for garbage collection, this all is dependent on the statefulness and expense of your object. If your worried about the state of your worker threads being compromised, you can look at using the flyweight pattern to encapsulate your state outside of the worker. Additionally, if you were to follow the [flyweight pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html), you can also look at how useful [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) objects would be in your application architecture.